A schematic representability of an algebraic space with group action
In the book "Néron Models" (BLR), there is a statement as follows (on page 164):
Let $S$ be a locally noetherian scheme and let $G$ be a smooth algebraic group space over $S$ with connected fibers. Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic space over $S$ with a $G$-action on $X$ and let $Y\subset X$ be an open subspace. Suppose that $GY=X$. Then
(b) If $Y$ is a scheme, then $X$ is a scheme.
(c) If $S$ is affine and if $Y$ is quasi-affine, any finite set of points of $X$ is contained in an affine open subset of $X$.
The authors first prove (c), then they conclude (b) by saying "(b) follows from (c)". I do not understand how to deduce (b) from (c).
Another question is that to get (b), is it essential to assume the smoothness of $X$？ From their proof, I do not see the use of the smoothness of $X$ (but the smoothness of $G$ is required).
Thank you in advance!

If all points have an affine neighborhood, you have a scheme by definition no? Is there a problem with the reduction Y scheme -> wlog S, Y affine?

You are right. I am dumb.

It's not that trivial (and nobody able to read this book is dumb), Why would an fppf sheaf which is locally Zariski be a Zariski sheaf? I can only justify that c) implies b) by the existence of the schematic locus. Maybe something I still don't see but then I would like to have an explanation :) Also, there is still no answer about the use of smoothness in the proof!

@MarsaultChabat sorry, I didn't mean to imply it was trivial, I was just trying to determine the sticking point. Not sure I'm parsing your statement about sheaves correctly (every fppf sheaf is a Zariski sheaf?), but what I had in mind was: The hypothesis gives a Zariski cover of X by affines, taking intersections you get a presentation of X as a coequalizer of affines and open immersions, i.e. a scheme. I guess when proving the schematic locus you do the same thing for the maximal subspace which has such a cover.

Yes of course fppf implies Zariski you are completely right and I did write my comment too quickly :) But for me c) gives us an fppf cover (by affine), and what I was struggling with I guess is that I can't see why this is actually a Zariski cover (by affine).. In over words, why a quotient of an affine by an étale relation should give a scheme?

@MarsaultChabat surely "open affine subset of X" means open immersion from an affine, giving a Zariski cover. An etale relation on an affine scheme certainly does not have to yield a scheme.
